# Parametrizing polynomials with given Galois group

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-groups

Consider a transitive group $G \subset S_n$, and the set $E$ of polynomials in $\mathbb{K}[x]$ of degree $n$ with Galois group $\subset G$. I am looking for a rational surjective mapping $\varphi: \mathbb{K}^{n+1} \rightarrow E$. Is the Zariski closure of $E$ always of dimension $n+1$? Does such rational $\varphi$ always exists, at least for a field $\mathbb{K}$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I know that what I am asking is stronger that the inverse Galois problem, but maybe a negative answer is possible. For small groups, a positive answer is interesting. For $G=A_3$, it is easy a to build such parametrization on $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$. I would be particularly interested in the cases $D_5 \subset S_5$ and $D_7 \subset S_7$.

Comment: Perhaps there's something relevant in the book Constructive Polynomials, by Jensen, Ledet, and Yui? http://library.msri.org/books/Book45/files/book45.pdf

Comment: Consider the tower $\mathbb A^n \to \mathbb A^n/G \to \mathbb A^n/S_n = \mathbb A^n$. The $K$ points of the base parametrize degree $n$ polynomials with the fiber corresponding to the set of it's roots. Moreover, the image of $\mathbb A^n/G (K)$ inside $\mathbb A^n/S_n (K)$ is exactly your $E$, the set of polynomials with Galois group contained in $G$. Now in certain nice cases $\mathbb A^n/G$ itself might be (uni)rational in which case you are in luck. If not, then I don't know if this method can be boosted up to give a negative answer.

Comment: BTW I am using monic polynomials here but if you insist on considering all polynomials, it would be better to pass to projective space to kill the scaling action. What I am suggesting won't substantially change in that case.

Comment: Yes, you are right, probably the question would be better in projective space. The question can indeed be rewritten in terms of building a rational parametrization of the manifold given by the invariants conditions. But even for $A_n$, this is delicate: is $\Delta=r^2$ rationally parametrizable?

Comment: In the quintic case we know parametrizations that capture Galois groups in $F_5$. But again, to get from there to $D_5$ requires rationalizing the condition that the discriminant is a square.

Comment: I would recommend looking at Serre's book "Topics in Galois Theory" as he considers closely related problems. What you are asking for looks very similar to Noether's approach to the inverse Galois problem.